# Creating a datetime object by only providing the month or only providing the day of the week

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

Creating a `datetime` object in Python by only providing the month preserves the month information:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Feb', '%b')
datetime.datetime(1900, 2, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Feb', '%b').strftime('%B')
'February'
```

Since no year or day is provided, Python uses the defaults 1900 and 01, respectively, resulting in `datetime.datetime(1900, 2, 1, 0, 0)`.

However, if a day of the week is provided:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue', '%a')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue', '%a').strftime('%A')
'Monday'
```

I understand that `1900-01-01` was Monday, but why isn't Python creating an object `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 0, 0)` which was the first Tuesday after `1900-01-01`, similar to what it does with February in the first example?

It seems like the initial information (i.e. that the day was Tuesday) is lost without any warning or error. Is there a fundamental difference between creating a `datetime` object by only providing the month and only providing the day of the week?

Comment: I believe, that `datetime` stores year, month, day, and time fields. While the day of the week is calculated on demand. But that's not an answer to your question

Comment: @Yevhen you're right, I suppose that's why `datetime.datetime.strptime('', '')` works and results in `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)`. Yet I'd expect some sort of `ValueError` like `"Tue" cannot be used` since it basically removes the original piece of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail):

> For the `datetime.strptime()` class method, the default value is 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000: any components not specified in the format string will be pulled from the default value.

And important part:

> Similar to %U and %W, %V is only used in calculations when the day of
> the week and the ISO year (%G) are specified in a strptime() format
> string. Also note that %G and %Y are not interchangeable.

I guess `%a` falls under the same condition but isn't specified in the docs.

You could use `%G` (ISO 8601 year) with `%V` (ISO 8601 week) alongside with `%a`, then it should work:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('1900 01 Tue', '%G %V %a').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %a')
'1900-01-02 Tue'

>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('1900 02 Tue', '%G %V %a').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %a')
'1900-01-09 Tue'
```

I believe it's because this way you specify the needed week.